# Array assignment in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I am a novice as far as python programming is introduced. Currently I am trying to understand one python program as per my requirement. While going through program,I found this confusing statement:

```
circleMap = [np.average(map[:, 0]), np.average(map[:, 1]), np.average(map[:, 2])]

  map= globalMap[self.yPos, self.xPos:(self.xPos+self.width)]
```

So my question is,

1. Is map a 2 dimensional array?
2. What is dimension of circleMap?
3. what `circleMap = [np.average(map[:, 0]), np.average(map[:, 1]), np.average(map[:, 2])]` does?

I checked in internet, but could not find any useful link.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. the `map` here is an numpy array with ***at least*** 2 dimensions;
2. `circleMap` is a 1D builtin list, because `np.average` here returns a float;
3. `circleMap = [np.average(map[:, 0]), np.average(map[:, 1]), np.average(map[:, 2])]` creates a python builtin list storing the mean value of each column of `map`.

**Note:** since `map` is a python builtin function, you should not make it a variable name in practice.

### EDIT:

"what does gMap contain? `gMap= globalMap[self.yPos, self.xPos:(self.xPos+self.width)]` Is this statement used for initializing gMap?"

Yes it creates variable `gMap` which is a subarray of `globalMap`. It's on `globalMap`'s row `self.yPos`, column `self.xPos` to `self.xPos+self.width`.

Answer (score 0):

1) `map` is indeed a 2 dimensional array (the comma in `[:,0]` indicates at least 2 dimensions). Here, `:` means all elements. It is confusing, as `map` is also a function in python, so that's certainly not good practice. We can infer that it has at least 3 variables.

2) Indeed, `circleMap` will be a list with 3 elements in it.

3) `map` has 3 variables in it so to speak. What the code does is store the average for each of the three variables in a list. You can access them like `circleMap[0]`, `circleMap[1]` and `circleMap[2]` respectively.

`np.average` is really similar to `np.mean`, the latter also takes weighting optionally.

In fact, it would have been much easier for the coder to have used `np.average(map[:,3], 1)`, which would give the exact same result (only stored in a numpy array, but with same dimensionality as the current `circleMap`). The fact the coder did not do this can mean 3 things I assume:

- The coder is a beginner
- The variable has 3 or more dimensions (you might end up with 2d array if you'd use `np.average(map[:,3], 1)`)

To address the last part consider the following example:

```
yPos = 1
xPos = 1
width = 2
globalMap = np.array([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]])    # 3x4 array
globalMap[yPos, xPos:(xPos+width)] # this will evaluate to:
globalMap[1, 1:3]  # note that python is zero indexed so that the result will be
array([6,7])
```

Best is to play around with it for yourself. Look at the contents of objects. `globalMap.shape` will give you the dimensions of the array.

Another side note is that, confusingly, the coder uses `y` to indicate the row (which is usually denoted by `x`)

Comment: The `self` indicate that `yPos` and `xPos` are objects of a class.

Comment: The coder is basically overwriting `map`. globalMap is another (probably 2d) array, of which some row is subset. Note that several columns are selected; he is selected all elements from the x position up until x position + width.

Comment: So, what is content of map array? I am from C?C++ background, so I find it really confusing.

Comment: The content can be anything, but it will have 1 row, and `width` number of columns. Practically, it'll be a 1d vector with size `width`.

Comment: Another advice would be to use a Python interpreter so you can play with objects in "real-time" (if you're not already using it).